# Extract IP from a MySQL Column

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my column description in a table:

Description:

> [Kubernetes] Node under disk pressure is Triggered on kubernetes.node.name = 10.123.199.6 and kubernetes.cluster.name = tst-udf-tst-qa for kube-bskm5qvw0ldcni69dqn0-test-qa-00001796.iks.ibm

I need to see only the IP address from this description column like below:

```
IP Address
10.123.199.6
10.123.199.7
10.123.199.8 ..
```

Could you please help to create a query for this?

Comment: Please share what query or regex you have tried and explain where it's not working.

Comment: Something here should get you started. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: #1. Do you guarantee that IP addresses are (1) IPv4 (2) canonical? #2. If the value contains none IP - do you need the output for this row (with empty string or NULL)? #3. If the value contains more than one IP address then what is desired output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Akina 
1. Yes, the IP addresses are IPV4. 
2. I don't need the values doesn't contain the IP.
3. No, The description doesn't contain more than one IP.

Comment: @Stu
I have tried the below query:
REGEXP_EXTRACT([description],'(IP Address[ :0-9.]+([\r\n]+[0-9.]+)+)') AS IP_Add

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` here:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}') AS ip_addr
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: I'm using:
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.51, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

The above query is not supported  my server.

Comment: You might want to consider upgrading if you think you will have a long term need for this query.

Comment: Is there any other option to get IP address only from a column?